# Increasing the number of processors causes MPI to slow down

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I think maybe I'm not understanding some fundamental aspect of MPI here, but using 4 processes, here is the breakdown using `time ./main`:

```
13.00 real         4.99 user         3.05 sys
13.00 real         4.84 user         2.87 sys
13.00 real         4.91 user         2.84 sys
13.00 real         5.18 user         3.04 sys
```

So it seems like CPU time for each process only takes around 5 seconds, yet the total elapse time is much longer than that. Why is this, if the processes are being run in parallel then shouldn't the total elapsed time be much closer to 5 seconds?

If I execute with 1 process, I get

```
9.92 real         8.49 user         0.88 sys
```

The code in question is assembling a somewhat large matrix (120,000 x 120,000 in size) and solving a linear system. The only place I can think of in the code I can think of that would be slowing down would be in the linear solve, but I'm using the `superlu_dist` package to solve, which is specifically meant for solving in parallel.

So can someone help me to understand these results?

Comment: Could be a bad implementation of MPI. The `user` and `sys` times refers to time that the CPU is doing work. `real` is the wallclock time and is going to include all the blocking time in which the CPUs sit doing nothing (with respect to that process) useful. The intercommunication overhead must be quite large. Maybe tell us about your setup?

Comment: @hayesti I can edit my post with some pseudocode, although the code itself is quite dense right now. I'll do my best to simplify it to a minimal example

Comment: It would be useful if you tell us what MPI implementation and type of machine you're using for your experiments.